# Regex to validate comma separated year range

Tags: javascript, regex

I came up with this regex:

```
(?:[0-9]{4}-([0-9]{4}|[?]))+
```

for this text:

```
1993-2000,2004-?
```

The regex to capture on block = `[0-9]{4}-([0-9]{4}|[?])`

I have variations like:

```
1993-?
1993-2000
1993-2000,2004-?
1993-2000,2004-2010
```

and so on.

My regex captures the blocks `[1993-2000]` and `[2004-?]`, but not the comma.

What I find hard is to declare the comma should be mandatory for the second, third, etc. occurrences.

So what should not be allowed is:

```
1993-2000,
1993-20002007-?
?-2000
```

Possibly this could be allowed to0: `1993-2000,2004,2007,2010-?`

Can someone help me get this last understanding about a conditional comma for second and followup occurrences?

I found this regex which I adapted a bit:

```
^([0-9]{4}(-([0-9]{4}|[?]))?)(,([0-9]{4}(-([0-9]{4}|[?]))?))*$
```

Seems to do the trick, but is this the best version?

Answer (score 2):

Your regex (the last one) looks good enough. There should be no problem about over-rejecting or over-accepting. There are 2 unnecessary groupings, though:

```
^[0-9]{4}(-([0-9]{4}|[?]))?(,[0-9]{4}(-([0-9]{4}|[?]))?)*$
```

You can make all the groups non-capturing, since you are validating and not going to capture any text:

```
^[0-9]{4}(?:-(?:[0-9]{4}|[?]))?(?:,[0-9]{4}(?:-(?:[0-9]{4}|[?]))?)*$
```

`\d` can be used in place of `[0-9]`, but I think it doesn't hurt to declare it clearly.